# Converting .doc Format to Pdf file in iphone

Tags: iphone

How do i Convert .doc format to pdf file from iphone .
i Want same layout as .doc format.
i Tried with html format but did not get any success.

anyone suggest any solution would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: For what reason? UIWebView can display .doc files.

Comment: i need to create pdf file in the same format as .doc has and then upload that pdf file to server. that's why i need the format to be same as .doc file but it would save in pdf file in local resource.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a PD based on a DOC [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) might help.  The cloud system can work from an iPhone as long as you are happy calling a web service.